# How to make relation of users table and other with none primary key on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have users table assigned a foreign key(clinic_uuid, not primary key) to clinics table as below command.

```
$table->foreign('clinic_uuid',100)->references('clinic_uuid')->on('clinics');
```

After migration, I added 'hasmany users' relation to Clinic model.

```
public function users(){
 return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

And also 'belongsTo Clinic' relation to User model

```
public function clinic(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Clinic::class,'clinic_uuid');
}
```

After that I add a few to clinics table.

```
    clinic_uuid       name
----------------------------------
       a1111       dog clinic
       a2222       cat clinic
```

And also users table.

```
  id    clinic_uuid       name
----------------------------------
  1       a1111           jame
  2       a1111           matt
```

Then, I try on my controller as below code but I get only null.

```
Auth::user()->clinic()->get();   --> get null
User::find(1)->clinic()->get();  --> get null
```

Appreciated for all advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to tell Eloquent what the local and foreign keys are for both relationships as neither of them follow the default convention:

```
public function clinic()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Clinic::class, 'clinic_uuid', 'clinic_uuid');
}
```

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'clinic_uuid', 'clinic_uuid');
}
```

Since the column names for both tables are the same it doesn't matter for this example but you can always refer to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) to figure out which column name should go where in the relationship methods.

Comment: Since tried several. It work now but I have to set 'clinic_uuid' on clinics table as a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
User::with('clinic')->findOrFail(auth()->id());
```

Try to use eager loading [Laravel Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It return users table instead clinics. I need clinic information that related 'clinic_uuid'. E.g. user id = 1, return clinic name 'dog clinic'

Comment: dd this in relationship column you will get that data like this $user->clininc->clinic_uuid